# PHP HTML entities: comparing chars with the html code (acute)

Tags: php, html, entity

How can i make this comparison return true?

```
$var1="á";
$var2="&aacute;";

if ($var1==$var2) {
    return true;
}
```

The funny thing is that i dont know if the html entity is in var1 or in var2, so i need to put the same function in both sides of the comparison.

I tried with html_entity_decode, htmlentities and a combination of both.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you know which side contains HTML entities if at all? That makes comparisons virtually impossible and you're down to guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just use an `or` comparison in your if statement? If either `$var1` or `$var2` is a HTML entity, it should return true nicely.

```
<?php 
    $var1="á";
    $var2="&aacute;";

    if (html_entity_decode($var1)==$var2 || html_entity_decode($var2)==$var1) {
        return true;
    }
?>
```

If you might have them in boht or either field, you could add in a third comparison like this:

```
<?php 
    $var1="á";
    $var2="&aacute;";

    if ($var1==$var2 || html_entity_decode($var1)==$var2 || html_entity_decode($var2)==$var1) {
        return true;
    }
?>
```